# Ember cli - use sass addon in less project

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs, ember-cli-addons

I use broccoli-less in my ember cli project and would like to use an addon ([ember-cli-materialize](https://github.com/truenorth/ember-cli-materialize)), which uses broccoli-sass.

After installing the addon, i get: File to read not found or unreadable ../app.scss, because i also have an app.less file in my styles dir.

As i understand, this commit [Allow multiple preprocessors per type](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/1033) should make it possible, although i might be missing something. Has anyone managed to use ember-cli with multiple preprocessors, and what changes is needed?

Ember-cli version: 1.13.1

Ember version: 1.12.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know your circumstance is different than mine but this may help others or spur a better solution. I was added to a dev team to polish up an app already styled using LESS. I favor SASS and tried to use ember-cli-sass alongside ember-cli-less without any success.

You may want to look further into [Ember-Cli's add.import](http://www.ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies/)

By adding your input configurations to `ember-cli-build.js` with the above, you can leverage either your `bower-components` directory (if used) or `vendor` directory, to import a compiled CSS doc (from Sass source files) that will build alongside the project quite nicely with a simple `sass --watch <input:output>` command.

The LESS files are ultimately compiled to `app.css`, and your SASS files to `vendor.css` (make sure you link to the stylesheet in your index page/template).